# Updating location in background in Android Oreo

Tags: android, firebase

I am targeting Android Oreo. My requirement is to send user location to the server at every 5 minutes, Should I use Firebase Job Scheduler or Foreground Service Or any other good recommendation from you ?

Comment: Foreground Service

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer . Can you please let me know why foreground service is better than Firebase job dispatcher in mt scenario ?

Comment: do u know form which version Job SchedulerAPI is available

Comment: @hasibuzzamanchowdhury Stack Overflow is not a platform for giving you all the code solutions. Till now what you have done , were did you got stuck with code sample if you update, then you can expect better answers

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar Firebase Job Schedular is available from api level 9+ .
 Got this from the official documentation in this [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)

Comment: so can use Job Scheduler